# Redirect Page After Login in ES6 Fetch

Tags: javascript, authentication, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

I need help after logging in of user. I tried to redirect the page if the data has result but if I log in an incorrect email or password, it still redirects the page rather than alerting an error. I'm using tokens from API by the way.

```
function loginUser(){

fetch('http://example_website.com/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
    })
})
.then(data => data.json() )
.then(data =>  { 

    if(data){
        redirect: window.location.replace("../Sample/home.html") 
    } else{
        alert("Invalid Email or Password");
    }
}) 
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

}

```
function registerUser(){

fetch('http://example_website.com/api/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        given_name: document.getElementById("given_name").value,
        last_name: document.getElementById("last_name").value,
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value,
        password_confirmation: document.getElementById("confirm_password").value
    })
})
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data =>  { console.log(data); 
})
.catch((err) => {
     alert ("Error!");
    console.error(err);
})
}
```

Valid API response:

[image: Correct]

Invalid API resopnse:

[image: Invalid]

Comment: when you debug your code, what do you get in the `data` variable in this line `.then(data => data.json())` for both cases successfully authenticated or not

Comment: @randomguy04. I got the response from the api. Like if the user logs in correctly, the response is login successful and it has a token. If not, it will say validation failed. I tried to use console.log(data) to see the result in browser console. It all comes from the login api

Comment: can you edit your question and post the API response when the validation fails please?

Comment: @randomguy04. Pls check image above. I already edited it

Comment: have you tried the answer below?

Comment: @randomguy04. Thanks. It works. Please upvote my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are running this piece of code

```
.then(data =>  { 

    if(data){ //here!
         redirect: window.location.replace("../Sample/home.html") 
    } else{
        alert("Invalid Email or Password");
    }
})
```

`data` is always a truthy value, because it is an object with content, what you want to do, is to validate `data.response` instead like:

```
.then(data =>  { 

    if(data.response){
         redirect: window.location.replace("../Sample/home.html") 
    } else{
        alert("Invalid Email or Password");
    }
})
```

Comment: The register function also has an error. I have a popup button. It closes the popup despite there's an error and if the fields are not completely filled out. I have put "required" but still no effect.

Comment: you have edited the original question, please post another question with the relevant code for that specific error and i'd be glad to help